# How to pass parameter on windows command line during run a bat file

Tags: batch-file, jasperserver

I am trying to run a bat file to Installs JasperReports Server, sample data,
and sample databases.
Command is

`D:\Software\Jasper_CE_set_and_war\jasperreports-server-cp-6.0.1-bin\buildomatic>js-install-ce.bat`

then i got error is

Too many arguments

```
Please enter one of the following options: 'EMPTY', minimal, regen-config, drop-db, test
Invalid option specified
Please enter one of the following options: 'EMPTY', minimal, regen-config, drop-db, test
```

but when i pass one of the given parameter it is giving me same error.

```
D:\Software\Jasper_CE_set_and_war\jasperreports-server-cp-6.0.1-bin\buildomatic>js-instal
st
Invalid option specified
Please enter one of the following options: 'EMPTY', minimal, regen-config, drop-db, test
```

[image]

Content of bat file

```
@ECHO OFF

rem ///
rem /// JasperReports Server CE installation script.
rem ///
rem /// Usage: js-install-ce.bat {option:(<EMPTY>|minimal|drop-db|regen-config|test)}
rem ///

CALL "bin/do-js-install.bat" ce %%**
```

Tried with only 
CALL "bin/do-js-install.bat" ce %%**
[image]
but result remain same.
Any clue what is going wrong ?

Comment: try adding an argument to the .bat file, like `minimal` for instance. I guess the error message is not correct. If it does not fix it, can you post or link to the contents of the .bat file?

Comment: try with an argument. There seems to be a but somewhere in the install script.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i tried with set arg=minimal
CALL "bin/do-js-install.bat" ce arg %%** but it didn't work.

Comment: Just try `CALL "bin/do-js-install.bat" ce`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre tried but  result remain same.Added snapshot in question. any clue to how we can solve this?

Comment: @Nand Did you check `do-js-install.bat`? You can try to add echo to this file for "debugging" purpose

Comment: @nand Why you pass arguments like %%**? The correct syntax is `CALL "bin/do-js-install.bat" ce %*`

Comment: @elzooilogico I tried with "%*" in that case it is giving this error " 'FIND' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'FIND' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
=1-4* was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @Nand what is the code _do-js-install.bat_? If you don't show your code, I could only guess what is going on. Please post at least the relevant parts of the actual code.

Comment: @AlexK when i am trying with "do-js-install.bat" in that case getting this error "'"./do-js-install.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @elzooilogico i am trying to  install the jasper server WAR file using js-install scripts: and following steps defined in http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-install-guide.pdf . At chapter 5 ,  in section 5.2,page 36 , see steps defined for "5. Run the js-install scripts.
"  i got stuck down there only. Installation bat file i have already posted in question. I don't have any thing else. It would great , if you can guide me from here.

Comment: That's not his code that's the software batch files. I agree that `%%**` is wrong. But on the other hand `FIND` should be found since it's the standard grep-like windows command. The batch files of this software have serious problems.

Comment: @nand Below the installation script table appear the following _If you encounter errors during the js-install script execution, see section 5.7.3, “Error Running js-install Scripts (jsinstall.bat/sh),”
on page 40_. Maybe you'll find a solution there

Comment: @elzooilogico i checked there.that saying that check log files but after running this script i don't get any log so no clue how to solve this issue.